# .Net Core 2.0 - Get AAD access token to use with Microsoft Graph

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

When starting up a fresh .Net Core 2.0 project with Azure AD Authentication you get a working sample that can sign in to your tenant, great!

Now I want to get an access token for the signed in user and use that to work with Microsoft Graph API.

I am not finding any documentation on how to achieve this. I just want a simple way to get an access token and access the graph API, using the template created when you start a new .NET Core 2.0 project. From there I should be able to figure out the rest.

Very important that it works with the project that gets created when following the process where you select Work and school accounts for authentication when creating a new 2.0 MVC Core app in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote a blog article which shows just how to do that: [ASP.NET Core 2.0 Azure AD Authentication](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication)

The TL;DR is that you should add a handler like this for when you receive an authorization code from AAD:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(opts =>
{
    Configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Bind(opts);

    opts.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
        {
            var request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
            var currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, request.Path);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);

            var distributedCache = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();
            string userId = ctx.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

            var cache = new AdalDistributedTokenCache(distributedCache, userId);

            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);

            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(currentUri), credential, ctx.Options.Resource);

            ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
        }
    };
});
```

Here my `context.Options.Resource` is `https://graph.microsoft.com` (Microsoft Graph), which I'm binding from config along with other settings (client id etc.).

We redeem a token using ADAL, and store the resulting token in a token cache.

The token cache is something you will have to make, here is the example from the [example app](https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth):

```
public class AdalDistributedTokenCache : TokenCache
{
    private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;
    private readonly string _userId;

    public AdalDistributedTokenCache(IDistributedCache cache, string userId)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _userId = userId;
        BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
        AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
    }

    private string GetCacheKey()
    {
        return $"{_userId}_TokenCache";
    }

    private void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        Deserialize(_cache.Get(GetCacheKey()));
    }

    private void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        if (HasStateChanged)
        {
            _cache.Set(GetCacheKey(), Serialize(), new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
            {
                AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
            });
            HasStateChanged = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The token cache here uses a distributed cache to store tokens, so that all instances serving your app have access to the tokens. They are cached per user, so you can retrieve a token for any user later.

Then when you want to get a token and use MS graph, you'd do something like (important stuff in `GetAccessTokenAsync()`):

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public HomeController(IDistributedCache cache, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _config = config;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> MsGraph()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage res = await QueryGraphAsync("/me");

        ViewBag.GraphResponse = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return View();
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> QueryGraphAsync(string relativeUrl)
    {
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" + relativeUrl);

        string accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();
        req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        return await Client.SendAsync(req);
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        string authority = _config["Authentication:Authority"];

        string userId = User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        var cache = new AdalDistributedTokenCache(_cache, userId);

        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, cache);

        string clientId = _config["Authentication:ClientId"];
        string clientSecret = _config["Authentication:ClientSecret"];
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", credential, new UserIdentifier(userId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

There we acquire a token silently (using the token cache), and attach it to requests to the Graph.

Comment: I can see this is from your github sample, which I already have ;) This does unfortunately not use the setup I am talking about (new->project->.net core 2.0-> AAD auth. You get an "extensions" folder there, and some other stuff your sample does not have etc. And you cannot add `.AddOpenIdConnect` without getting some odd error. I do not have my work computer until tomorrow. Will comment more then.

Comment: I see you even mention it at the end of your post :) You don't happen to have a sample that uses Work and school accounts for authentication when creating the new 2.0 MVC Core app ? I already tried integrating your sample into one of those projects with no success. Will try more tomorrow.

Comment: I think in that template you have to modify the extension method that adds the authentication. You should be able to apply this there quite easily.

Comment: Ill try ASAP tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: surprisingly I got it to work. Reading your blog helped understanding the flow a lot, thanks! I have one questions though. It feels like the `.AddAzureAd` part and the related Extension methods you get in the VS sample does a lot of what you do in your sample, so I might be doing some stuff twice. Or am I wrong? Because if I comment out the `.AddAzureAd` part it still works with just your `.AddOpenIdConnect` methods.

Comment: It does the same things. It just encapsulates the authentication handler configuration in an extension method so there is less code in Startup. So you can either do it like I did or modify the extension method to do the same thing.

Comment: Just spent the last 12 hours trying to find this answer. finally got it implemented so that no exceptions are thrown. I had to knock off for tonight `AquireTokenSilentAsync` is returning null. I believe I am missing the resource option somewhere along the way, or have a spelling error.

Comment: Is it possible to request access token again each time instead of caching and where would be the best place to do this? I ask because I am transferring from a project using IdentityServer that uses on-behalf flow and obtains new access token on each request.

Comment: You should make a new question for that

Comment: @Green_qaue did you have luck getting a clean version of this working with the default setup?  Have been looking for something based off of the starting template and still not having any luck.