# Azure AD b2b "Read all users' basic profiles" permission

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have delegated user permission `User.ReadBasic.All`.  In the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions), it states this

> "Allows the app to read a basic set of profile properties of other users in your organization on behalf of the signed-in user. This includes display name, first and last name, email address, open extensions and photo. Also allows the app to read the full profile of the signed-in user."

How can I get all users with basic profiles?

```
var accessToken = authContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret))
    .Result
    .AccessToken;

var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(requestMessage => {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));
```

**Can you please confirm my "Authority" URL is correct or not?**

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20User.Read%20User.ReadWrite%20User.ReadBasic.All";
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var accessToken = authContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret))
    .Result
    .AccessToken;
```

Comment: The authority should only be "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/common". I means that you want to get a token for any work and school account. What you have expressed is the full URI to get a token. It's not needed: ADAL builds it (among other things) for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are really getting a token from the cache (using `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`), whereas your token was really added in the cache when you have redeemed the authorization code produced by ASP.NET using the call to `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync`. you will find the explanation in ADAL.NET conceptual documentation : [Acquiring a token by authorization code in Web Apps](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-authorization-codes-on-web-apps)

Note that to call the graph you might rather want to use MSAL.NET. See for instance the following branch [signInAndCallMicrosoftGraph](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/signInAndCallMsGraph) of the sample named: [aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2). This is expressed as a tutorial, explaining first the sign-in phase, and then calling an API (in this case the Microsoft Graph)

Finally the authority you have used is not for Azure AD B2C (and as I mentioned in the comment on your question, for Azure AD, it should be reduced to `login.microsoftonline.com{tenantId}/common`)

Answer (score 2):

You can hit the Graph API `users/<email_id>` endpoint (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<email_id_of_the_user>`) with the proper Bearer token for getting the basic details of other users.

You can try that out in the Graph Explorer as well - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

[image]

Comment: Yes- This same thing if i'm doing in My c# project it response like: "code":"Authorization_RequestDenied" "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Comment: @NimeshGami - May be I din't get your query correctly. Are you getting a proper access token? If yes, paste that token in https://jwt.io/ and check whether you have required scopes in that token

Comment: If the scopes are missing in the token, then that means the user is yet to give consent and you might need to "Grant permission" from the azure portal. In the Authorization code/implicit flow of OAuth 2.0, the user will get a chance to give consent while logging in to the application. But as you are using the Resource owner password credentials flow, you might (not sure) wanna grant those permissions explicitly

Comment: Yes right i didn't find scope in token. Can you please help me how to correct my token I mean what change require to do?

Comment: @NimeshGami - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent

Comment: Added solution below - Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It is the same regardless of whether you use `User.ReadBasic.All` or `User.Read.All`: `

```
await graphServiceClient
    .Users
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

The only difference between the two will be in the result set. Properties that are inaccessible using `User.ReadBasic.All` will simply not be returned in the results.

Comment: I'm using the same code but now i found issue is in the access token i'm not found scope I've checked with using jwt.io. can you please suggest me how to get scope in access token?

Comment: How are you requesting your scopes?

Comment: Yes i'm passing scope, I have checked both with scope and without

Comment: I wasn't asking _if_ but rather _how_ you're requesting scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution and get users basic profile  of my organization. 
Solution: Get Access token using AcquireTokenSilentAsync method. [More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566717/net-core-2-0-get-aad-access-token-to-use-with-microsoft-graph)

```
options.Scope.Add("User.ReadBasic.All");

options.ResponseType = "code id_token";                

OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
{
    var request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
    var currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, request.Path);
    var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);

    var distributedCache = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();
    string userId = ctx.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

    var cache = new DistributedTokenCache(distributedCache, userId);

    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);

    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
        ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code,
        new Uri(currentUri),
        credential,
        ctx.Options.Resource);

    ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
}

services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();


private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
            string tenantId = User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
            authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
            string userId = (User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
            var cache = new DistributedTokenCache(_memoryCache, userId);
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, cache);
            string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
            string clientId = "XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX";
            string secret = "XXXX";
            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

Comment: Here you are really getting a token from the cache (using AcquireTokenSilentAsync), whereas your token was really added in the cache when you have redeemed the authorization code produced by ASP.NET using the call to AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync.