# Azure AD Access token in not found Scope (scp)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a multi-tenant application in Azure AD 
When I trying to get access token and check in jwt.io I found scp (Scope) is missing.

```
//string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20User.ReadWrite%20User.ReadBasic.All%20Sites.ReadWrite.All%20Contacts.ReadWrite%20People.Read%20Notes.ReadWrite.All%20Tasks.ReadWrite%20Mail.ReadWrite%20Files.ReadWrite.All%20Calendars.ReadWrite";
//string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?&scope=https://graph.windows.net/directory.read%20https://graph.windows.net/directory.write";
//string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
//string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
//string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20User.Read%20User.ReadWrite%20User.ReadBasic.All";
//string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/token?scope=User.ReadBasic.All";
//string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/token?scope=User.ReadBasic.All";
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?response_type=token&scope=User.ReadBasic.All";
```

I have tried many combinations for authority URL

```
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
string clientId = "XXXX";
string secret = "XXXX";
authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret)).Result;
```

[image]

How to get scope of microsoft.graph resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is delegated permissions which are presented to the resource at run-time as **"scp"** claims in the client's access token.

But you are using **Application** permission, which specify role-based access using the client application's credentials/identity, are presented to the resource at run-time as "**roles**" claims in the client's access token.

> "**Delegated**" permissions, which specify scope-based access using delegated authorization from the **signed-in resource owner**, are presented to the resource at run-time as "**scp**" claims in the client's access token.
>
> **Application** permissions, which specify role-based access using the client application's credentials/identity, are presented to the resource at run-time as "**roles**" claims in the client's access token.

---

> How to get scope of microsoft.graph resource?

We could get the answer from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#permissions).

> Permission requests are configured on the "**Applications**" / "Settings" tab in the Azure portal, under "Required Permissions", by selecting the desired "Delegated Permissions" and "Application Permissions" (the latter requires membership in the Global Admin role). Because a public client can't securely maintain credentials, it can only request delegated permissions, while a confidential client has the ability to request both delegated and application permissions. The client's application object stores the declared permissions in its requiredResourceAccess property.

[image]

Comment: One additional note, these instructions for selecting scopes are only applicable to v1 Apps. For v2 Apps, you need to define them in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. Step by step instructions can be found at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#4-get-an-access-token

Comment: I got solution and get users basic profile of my organization. Solution: Get Access token using AcquireTokenSilentAsync method. More Details

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734558/4689622

Thanks All